# Congruence and first odd primes

Tags: modular-forms

I tried to find the solutions to this modular equation:

$3^{(5+7+11+13+17+19+\dots +p(m-3)+p(m-2))} \equiv p(m-1) \bmod p(m) $

where $p(m)$ is the m-th odd prime number(note that it's three to the power of 5+7+11+13+...).

The only solution that I have found is $m=20$ or $p(m)=73$. Do any other such $m$ exist? What is the next one?

Comment: Is there any reason to think that there's any structure at all to this problem? I'm pretty sure the answer is just "sometimes it happens by coincidence, and mostly it doesn't", and that numerically searching for the next coincidence isn't too interesting.

Comment: @GregMartin: None that I see, but I humored the question with a few CPU-minutes.

Comment: Interesting or not,it depends on what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get different numbers: $p_{53} = 241$ and $p_{730692} = 11067691$ are the first two I find. I used this code ([PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)):

```
{n=4; s=0; q=5;
forprime(p=7,10^9,
  if(Mod(3,p)^(s%(p-1))==q,print(n" "p));
  n++;s+=q;q=p
)}
```

The standard heuristic says that there's about a 50/50 chance that the next term is less than $10^{20}.$

Comment: ,how far your searching area? is it below 10^9 ?

Comment: @BlueSky: This code searches for the largest prime less than $10^9$. I searched a bit higher on my own, maybe $2\cdot10^9.$ You could use this code to do your own search, replacing `10^9` with some other value.